# Is this map continuous w.r.t. the weak topology?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, reproducing-kernel-hilbert-spaces

I am currently working with kernels and I've stumbled upon a map that I really want it to be continuous, but I'm not seeing how to prove it (or disprove it). Consider the following map $\Phi: l_2(\mathbb{N}) \to \mathbb{R}$ given by $$\Phi(w) = C w_{i_1}^{j_1} w_{i_2}^{j_2}...w_{i_n}^{j_n},$$
where $i_1,...,i_n, j_1,...,j_n \in \mathbb{N}$, $C$ is some constant, and $w_i$ denotes the $i$-th component of $w\in l_2(\mathbb{N})$. In other words, given a square summable sequence, we simply select a finite number of its components, exponentiate them, and multiply everything.

Now, assuming that $l_2(\mathbb{N})$ is given the weak topology, and that $B_R$ denotes the closed ball of radius $R$ in $l_2$, is there any hope that $\Phi \in C(B_R)$, i.e. $\Phi$ is a continuous function on $B_R$? Note that $B_R$ is compact, by the Banach-Alaoglu theorem. I'm really not seeing how can I prove that $\Phi$ is continuous or discontinuous on $B_R$. Any suggestions?

Comment: You're working with kernels (positive definite?) and you say that you're assuming that $\ell ^2 (\mathbb N)$ has the weak topology. This does not make sense.

Comment: @ashK why is that? The topology on $l_2$ shouldn't affect the fact that my map $k: l_2 \times l_2 \to \mathbb{R}$ is of the form $\langle \Phi(x), \Phi(y) \rangle$ for an explicit feature map $\Phi$, thus a kernel. Am I missing something?

Comment: You added the tag of reproducing kernel. What is your definition of reproducing kernel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The weak topology is the smallest topology making all linear functionals continuous. In particular, the projections $π_i : l_2(\mathbb{N})\to \mathbb{R}$ given by $π_i(w) = w_i$ are continuous.

Moreover, any product of continuous maps is also continuous (multiplication on $\mathbb{R}$ is continuous). Hence, $f_{i,j}(w) = w_i^j$ is also a continuous map. Multiplying finitely many of these $f_{i,j}$ together gives you precisely your $\Phi$, which is thus continuous w.r.t. the weak topology on $B_R$.

Comment: Right... I was overthinking the problem completely. The projections are indeed linear and the rest follows easily from that. Thanks a lot!

Comment: It's actually continuous w.r.t. the weak topology on the whole $l_2(\mathbb{N})$. Right?

Comment: Yes! There is nothing we gain from restricting to $B_R$, the argumentation is valid on the entire space.

Answer (score 0):

I'll add an answer here just so I show the kernel I'm working with. In the comments someone pointed out that it doesn't make sense to work with kernels and weak topology. I don't see why is that. As a matter of fact, when I show that $k$ is a kernel I don't make any considerations about the topology in $l_2(\mathbb{N})$. So, let me know if you spot any fallacy.

I am considering a function $k: l_2(\mathbb{N}) \times l_2(\mathbb{N}) \to \mathbb{R}$ of the form $k(x,y) = K(\langle x,y\rangle_{l_2})$, where $K$ is an analytic function expressible globally by its Taylor series expanded at $0$, i.e.
$$K(t) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n t^n, \ \ \text{and so} \ \ k(x,y) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n \langle x,y \rangle_{l_2}^n.$$

As to why this is a kernel, I am using a Lemma from this [paper](https://papers.nips.cc/paper_files/paper/2010/file/4e0cb6fb5fb446d1c92ede2ed8780188-Paper.pdf). Namely:

> Lemma: Assume that $n\in \mathbb{N}$ is fixed. Then, for all $j \in \mathbb{N}_0^{\mathbb{N}}$ with $|j|:= \sum_{i =1}^\infty j_i=n$, there exists a constant $c_j \in (0,\infty)$ such that for all summable sequences $(b_i)_{i \in \mathbb{N}}\subset  [0,\infty)$ we have
> $$\left( \sum_{i=1}^\infty b_i \right)^n = \sum_{j \in \in \mathbb{N}_0^{\mathbb{N}} : |j| = n} c_j \prod_{i=1}^\infty b_i^{j_i}.$$

Now, by simply noting that

\begin{align*}
   k(x,y) =& \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n \langle x,y \rangle_{l_2}^n = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n \left( \sum_{i=1}^\infty x_i y_i \right)^n =  \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n \sum_{j \in \in \mathbb{N}_0^{\mathbb{N}} : |j| = n} \tilde{c}_j \prod_{i=1}^\infty (x_i y_i)^{j_i} = \\ 
    =& \sum_{j \in \mathbb{N}_0^\mathbb{N}} a_{|j|} \tilde{c}_j \prod_{i=1}^\infty x_i^{j_i} \prod_{i=1}^\infty y_i^{j_i},
  \end{align*}

and by setting $c_j = \sqrt{a_{|j|} \tilde{c}_j}$, we conclude that $\Phi: l_2 \to l_2(J)$ given by
$$\Phi(w) = \left( c_j \prod_{i=1}^\infty w_i^{j_i} \right)_{j \in J},$$
is a feature map of $k$, where we use the convention $0^0 =1$. In other words, $k(x,y) = \langle \Phi(x), \Phi(y) \rangle_{l_2(J)}$, thus is a kernel.

Comment: Moore Aronszajn theorem tells you that given a kernel $k$ on a set $X$, there is a unique Hilbert space $H$ whose reproducing kernel is $k$. So, kernel gives you the norm topology topology induced by the norm, correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Also, $k$ needs to be map from $\mathbb N \times \mathbb N \to \mathbb R$. This is exactly why I asked you for the definition.

Answer (score 0):

Since $\ell ^2 (\mathbb N )$ is a reproducing kernel Hilbert space, pointwise evaluation is continuous. Therefore for each $n$, the following map from $\ell ^2 (\mathbb N) \to \mathbb R$ sending $f \mapsto f(n)$ is continuous. In other words, the map $(x_i)_{i\in \mathbb N} \mapsto x_n$ is continuous for each $n\in \mathbb N$. The fact that your function $\Phi$ is continuous follows from the fact that it is product of pointwise evaluation functionals.

Note that weak topology is the smallest topology which makes every functional continuous and this is *not* included the definition for rkHs because it is unnecessary. In weak topology, the sequence $(e_i)_{i\in \mathbb N}$ converges to $0$. This certainly is not the case in the $\ell ^ 2 (\mathbb N)$.